# Proof by cases, inequality

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I have the following exercise:

> For all real numbers $x$, if $x^2 - 5x + 4 \ge 0$, then either $x \leq 1$ or $x \geq 4$.

I need you to help me to identify the cases and explain to me how to resolve that. Don't resolve it for me please.

Comment: Do you know the formula $x_{1,2} = \frac{-b +- \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{4a}$? Use that...

Comment: The expression factors as $(x-1)(x-4)$. The cases are $x\le 1$, $1\lt x\lt 4$, and $x\ge 4$.

Comment: Yeah, I factor the expression, but I need to textually prove that the individual cases are met... so as soon as I get (x-1)(x-4) how do I get from that to x ≤ 1 , x ≥ 4 because  what you are telling is clear but I cant seem to express it symbolically in a paper...

Comment: Case $x\ge 4$: Then $x-1\gt 0$, $x-4\ge 0$, and therefore $(x-1)(x-4)\ge 0$. Two more cases to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

If $(x-a)(x-b)\ge0$

Now the product of two terms is $\ge0$

So, either both $\ge0$ or both $\le0$

Now in either case, find the intersection of the ranges of $x$

Comment: So, the cases are when both are > than or equal to 0, and viceversa.

Comment: @DanielOrtizCosta, two cases namely, $x-a\ge0,x-b\ge0$ and $x-a\le0,x-b\le0$

Comment: Ok, so I have two cases, when both are positive, and when both are negative...

How do I work inside every case? do I get the value of x for each case?, in the first one x is greater than or equal to 1 and 4...

Comment: @DanielOrtizCosta, if $x\ge1$ and $x\ge 4,$ what can we conclude from this? Drawing the range in line should make things more clear

Comment: We can conclude that by transivity  x≥4

Comment: @DanielOrtizCosta, similarly, if $x\le 1$ and $x\le 4$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $x^2 -5x + 4 \geq 0$ then $(x-4)(x-1) \geq 0$.

Hint 2: By trichotomy, we know that either $x>0$, $x=0$, or $x<0$. Consider these three cases. Then It is clear that either $x>0$ or $x<0$. Now what happens if $x>0$ or $x<0$? How can you still satisfy the inequality? Try playing with some values...

Answer (score 0):

You already have the cases so I'm confused about the question. I assume you are asking how one gets to this. So let's focus on $x^2-5x+4$. We can factor this as

> $$x^2-5x+4=(x-1)(x-4)$$

So what we really have is...

> $$(x-1)(x-4)\geq 0$$

Notice that if $x\geq 4$, both $x-1$ and $x-4$ are not negative. So their product will be positive (or $0$). Now if $x \leq 1$, we know that $x-1$ and $x-4$ are both negative (or 0) so their product is either $0$ or a positive number. I'll leave it to you to check that if $1 < x < 4$ that their product is negative and hence doesn't satisfy what you want.